# How to import the Google Chat API discovery document into a Postman collection?

Tags: api, rest, postman, google-chat

I cannot get Postman to recognize  https://chat.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1

I normally import Swagger documents and it creates collections for me without any problems. But this is not a Swagger file, it's a Google "[discovery document](https://developers.google.com/discovery)". I would have thought that Postman would somehow recognize this Google format but it doesn't. Is says: "Error while importing: format not recognized...".

My question: Without adding all methods separately, how do I "consume" / import this API in a / as a Postman collection?

Answer (score 1):

I've not used it but you could try the [Google Discovery to OpenAPI 3.x Converter](https://github.com/stackql/google-discovery-to-openapi), which converts Google discovery documents to OpenAPI (Swagger) format.

Comment: Above converter works just fine thank you @Nexus !

Comment: No worries! Feel free to upvote my comment, I'm not sure why I was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I have found another maybe even better convertor (with online option too):
[api-spec-converter](https://lucybot-inc.github.io/api-spec-converter/)